# Save user decoded in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have a aplication where the user can take some pictures and send to the database, just as simple as that.

Everytime the user login he get a token, if everything fine with the token(he doesn't need to login).

I followed [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens) tutorial to do the **jwt** authentication, now i want to check on every request except(/login / register) that token and decode it to get the user info ( i am just saving the username, its unique so its fine).

So imagine i am routing to /flower?flowerName (random route) so in this route i want to create a register and save in my database some data, but before that as i said, i should enter a middleware that checks the permission.

**This is my middleware:**

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var jwtConfig = require('../config/jwt');

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
console.log("entered");

// check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
      console.log(req.headers['x-access-token']);
// decode token
if (token) {
    // verifies secret and checks exp
    jwt.verify(token,jwtConfig.secret, function (err, decoded) {
        if (err) {
            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
        } else {
            console.log("HEREE");
            // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
            req.decoded = decoded;
            console.log(req.decoded);
            next();
        }
    });
} else {
    // if there is no token
    // return an error
    return res.status(403).send({
        success: false,
        message: 'No token provided.'
    });
}
```

}

my problem is, how can i get the userID for my middleware and then save it in my next route? can i pass it trough the next? like next(userID)????
How can i get the parameter then.

**this is where i save the register:**

```
    var express = require('express');
var User = require('../models').User;
var Foto = require('../models').Foto;
var router = express.Router();
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var fs = require('fs');
var fsPath = require('fs-path');


module.exports = {
    sendPicture: function (req, res,next) {
        var bitmap = new Buffer(req.body.base64, 'base64');
        var dummyDate = "25/04/14-15:54:23";
        var lat = req.params.lat;
        var lon = req.params.lon;
        var alt = req.params.alt;
        var path = __dirname + "/../public/images/" + req.params.flowerName + "/example3.png";
        var fotoPath = ""
        var userId = 1;
        console.log(lat);
        console.log(lon);
        console.log(alt);
        console.log(req.query.token);
        fsPath.writeFile(path, bitmap, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.stack);
                return err;
            }
            Foto.create({
                image: path,
                userId: userId
            }).then(function () {
                return res.status(200).json({ message: "foto created" });
            }).catch(function(err){
                console.log(err.stack);
            })

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass any state variables through the whole chain through `res.locals`, i.e.

```
res.locals.decoded = decoded;
next();
```

you can find the details on res.locals [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals)